# Why am I getting this error in the bowser net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED?

Tags: django, nginx, vuejs2, django-rest-framework

I'm using Djangorestframework, nginx, vue.js in my demo_blog on my vps server. When I'm trying to log in to my demo_blog getting `http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/login/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I can log in to my admin panel without any problem, but my rest api is getting that error.

In my vue.js app my baseURL at that moment looks like `axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://ip_of_my_server/`. I made `npm run build` and then put the `dist` to the server.

In my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` I have that

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ip_of_my_server;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/demo_blog.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/demo_blog/staticfiiles/;
    }

    location /dist/ {
        alias /var/www/demo_blog/dist/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
```

In my file `demo_blog/gunicorn.conf.py` I have that

```
  bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'                                                                                                                            
  workers = 3                                                             
  user = "nobody"
```

I really cannot figure it out.

Comment: If it's on a VPS, you can't access it through localhost unless you forwarded you local compute 8000 port to the server's one. did you ?

Comment: note that localhost is your local computer. If you typed that on your browser, it'll try to connect to your desktop/laptop instead of your vps

Comment: Yes, it's on a VPS.